# What to do if I want to ask a question that is almost identical to an old question, but with a key difference?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, asking-questions

Recently I asked a question about filtering a dataset within a certain date interval in SQL. I got some good responses, but then realized I forgot to mention I was actually using HIVE/hiveQL, so the answers didn't actually end up helping me. If I were to submit basically the same question, but this time specify I am using hiveQL, would it still be marked as a duplicate?

Comment: Um, well you already did.  I'm personally not familiar enough with the differences among the various options in SQL.  I think your best bet is to ask the question only if the other one did not solve your problem.  In that case, it's easy to point to your old question and mention in the new one the extra constraints.  Basically, it depends on how important the "key difference" is.

Comment: Ask away! Better a new question, than an updated question that invalidates answers. Choose the lesser evil!

Answer (score 58):

In short: Ask, relate, explain the difference, wait for answers.

Comment: ... and be ready to defend your question if users TL;DR and close-vote it.

Answer (score 6):

Simply put the older post link in your question and explain how it's slightly different from your current post.

Comment: And the best way is to explain in terms as to why that question doesn't meet you're scenario. E.g. "That question deals specifically with file based configuration setup at compile time, but that doesn't help me because I am loading configuration dynamically in a multi-tenant system."

Comment: This is what I do if I have a similar question. I'll [inline link](/) it, usually as one of the first things in my post.

Comment: What Qix said. It's especially important to have the link very close to the beginning of the question, so all those people who can't read more two lines of text won't close-vote it.